# How can I align two divs horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I need to align two divs next to each other, so that each contains a title and a list of items, similar to:

```
<div>
    <span>source list</span>
    <select size="10">
        <option />
        <option />
        <option />
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <span>destination list</span>
    <select size="10">
        <option />
        <option />
        <option />
    </select>
</div>
```

It's remarkably easy to do with tables, but I don't want to use tables. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @TylerH, how is this a duplicate of a question asked nearly a year after this was asked?

Comment: age of the question is only one aspect to consider when closing questions as a duplicate; the far more important aspect to consider is which question has better answers and covers not only the second question, but others as well. This is called a canonical question. In this case, there are 8 answers that say "float" and 2 that say "use flexbox". The other question contains solutions that cover both of those *and more*, making it a better target.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Float the divs in a parent container, and style it like so:

```css
.aParent div {
    float: left;
    clear: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="aParent">
    <div>
        <span>source list</span>
        <select size="10">
            <option />
            <option />
            <option />
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>destination list</span>
        <select size="10">
            <option />
            <option />
            <option />
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you give an element a float, it is redundant at best to also give it a `clear:none`.

Comment: This was answered when some older browsers didn't always enforce the `clear:none` with floats.

Answer (score 39):

Nowadays, we could use some [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to align those divs.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <span>source list</span>
        <select size="10">
            <option />
            <option />
            <option />
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>destination list</span>
        <select size="10">
            <option />
            <option />
            <option />
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know of `display: flex`. Added the link so people will easily see the CSS3 background.

Comment: Even Edge can implement it correctly! Chrome, watta faq?! Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit) [not working in it...]

Comment: The same in Opera [not working]!

Comment: In 2021, all modern browsers support the flex. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

```
<div>
<div style="float:left;width:45%;" >
    <span>source list</span>
    <select size="10">
        <option />
        <option />
        <option />
    </select>
</div>

<div style="float:right;width:45%;">
    <span>destination list</span>
    <select size="10">
        <option />
        <option />
        <option />
    </select>
</div>
<div style="clear:both; font-size:1px;"></div>
</div>
```

Clear must be used so as to prevent the float bug (height warping of outer Div).

```
style="clear:both; font-size:1px;
```

Comment: What does the final nested div do?  Why `clear:both`?  why `font-size:1px` ?

Comment: To clear the floats. I believe the "font-size: 1px" is an IE compatibility thing. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **[float the divs](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp)** in required direction eg `left` or `right`.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap them both in a container like so:

```css
.container{ 
    float:left; 
    width:100%; 
}
.container div{ 
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div>
        <span>source list</span>
        <select size="10">
            <option />
            <option />
            <option />
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>destination list</span>
        <select size="10">
            <option />
            <option />
            <option />
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The container itself doesn't have to be floated.

Answer (score 3):

Add a class to each of the divs:

```css
.source, .destination {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.source {
    margin-right: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="source">
    <span>source list</span>
    <select size="10">
        <option />
        <option />
        <option />
    </select>
</div>
<div class="destination">
    <span>destination list</span>
    <select size="10">
        <option />
        <option />
        <option />
    </select>
</div>
```

That's a generic percentages solution - using pixel-based widths is usually much more reliable. You'll probably want to change the various margin/padding sizes too.

You can also optionally wrap the HTML in a container div, and use this CSS:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will ensure subsequent content does not wrap around the floated elements.

Answer (score 3):

`float` is obsolete, better use `display: flex;`:

example :

`.parent-div{ display: flex; }`

indicate the direction by `flex-direction: row/column;`.
go down if no space by `flex-wrap: wrap/nowrap;`

more properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Answer (score 1):

if you have two divs, you can use this to align the divs next to each other in the same row:

```css
#keyword {
    float:left;
    margin-left:250px;
    position:absolute;
}

#bar {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="keyword">
Keywords:
</div>
<div id="bar">
    <input type = textbox   name ="keywords" value="" onSubmit="search()" maxlength=40>
    <input type = button   name="go" Value="Go ahead and find" onClick="search()">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#floatingDivs{float:left;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="floatingDivs">
    <span>source list</span>
    <select size="10">
        <option />
        <option />
        <option />
    </select>
</div>

<div id="floatingDivs">
    <span>destination list</span>
    <select size="10">
        <option />
        <option />
        <option />
    </select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An id may be used only once.

Comment: It can be used more than once, but shouldn't be.

Answer (score -2):

For your purpose, I'd prefer using position instead of floating:

http://jsfiddle.net/aas7w0tw/1/

Use a parent with relative position:

```
position: relative;
```

And children in absolute position:

```
position: absolute;
```

In bonus, you can better drive the dimensions of your components.